# Where can i download latest stable bitcoin-core src files?

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling

i want to download latest stable `bitcoin-core src` files. and want to `build` it on my system from `source`.

here is latest `src` of `bitcoin-core` but its not stable for production ready environment.

```
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin
```

https://bitcoin.org/en/download shows latest version as

```
Latest version: 0.14.2
```

---

Update 1 :

Looks like `git checkout` is what i am looking for.

Comment: hmmm, 14.2 is latest version, stable. What do you mean by not being stable for your production environment?

Comment: @pebwindkraft i did git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin , compile, build after running and doing bitcoin-cli getinfo i am getting  "errors": "This is a pre-release test build - use at your own risk - do not use for mining or merchant applications"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `git clone git@github.com:bitcoin/bitcoin.git`
2. `git checkout tag_name`

the latest version must be v0.15.0.1 now. so the command is :
`git checkout v0.15.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You have to know which version is currently 'stable'. It's currently the 0.14 version. Just checkout the 0.14 branch from github. This will track 0.14.x versions.

You git pull and then make. Simples!

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone git@github.com:bitcoin/bitcoin.git

git tag
```

Find latest stable version (without "rc" on its name)

```
git checkout tag_name
```

*"rc" stands for release candidate